# how to create table with predefined values in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a JPA entity like this

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USAGE_THRESHOLD_ACTION")
public class CloudThresholdAction implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3170266806936216198L;

    /** The permission id. */

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "THRESHOLD_ID")
    private int thresholdActionId;

    /** The permission name. */
    @Column(name = "THRESHOLD_ACTION", unique = true)
    private String thresholdAction;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "cloudThresholdAction")
    private List<CloudAlarmConfig> cloudAlarmConfigs;

    /**
     * @param thresholdActionId
     *            the thresholdActionId to set
     */
    public void setThresholdActionId(int thresholdActionId) {
        this.thresholdActionId = thresholdActionId;
    }

    /**
     * @return the thresholdActionId
     */
    public int getThresholdActionId() {
        return thresholdActionId;
    }

    /**
     * @param thresholdAction
     *            the thresholdAction to set
     */
    public void setThresholdAction(String thresholdAction) {
        this.thresholdAction = thresholdAction;
    }

    /**
     * @return the thresholdAction
     */
    public String getThresholdAction() {
        return thresholdAction;
    }

    /**
     * @param cloudAlarmConfigs
     *            the cloudAlarmConfigs to set
     */
    public void setCloudAlarmConfigs(List<CloudAlarmConfig> cloudAlarmConfigs) {
        this.cloudAlarmConfigs = cloudAlarmConfigs;
    }

    /**
     * @return the cloudAlarmConfigs
     */
    public List<CloudAlarmConfig> getCloudAlarmConfigs() {
        return cloudAlarmConfigs;
    }

}
```

Now the set of values for the table will be fixed. Is there any way I can pass the values in the entity object when hibernate loads all java persistence classes so that the table will be created with some predifined values, rather than empty table ?

Trying to have a set of values like below when the table is created

```
+--------------+------------------+
| THRESHOLD_ID | THRESHOLD_ACTION |
+--------------+------------------+
|            2 | delete           |
|            3 | email            |
|            4 | notification     |
|            1 | shutdown         |
+--------------+------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

you can provide a default value to thresholdAction like

thresholdAction = "defaultThresholdAction";

or you can use PrePersist annotation.

```
private String thresholdAction;

@PrePersist
public void prePersist() {
    if(thresholdAction==null||thresholdAction.isEmpty()) 
        thresholdAction= "defaultThresholdAction";
}
```

@PrePersist is  Executed before the entity manager persist operation is actually executed or cascaded. This call is synchronous with the persist operation.

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/listeners.html

Hope this helps.Cheers.

Comment: actually trying to get a set of values when the table is created by entitymanager. So that the entries will be available by deploying the app in tomcat...edited my question with the values.

Answer (score 0):

You can add import.sql into root of your classpath with some insert statements.
import.sql will be executed after ddl schema generation is completed.